# Conditional formatting in Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets

Struggling like hell with this one but bet it's so simple!
Can do it in Libre but not in Google :-(
What I want to do is:
I have a range of cells with numbers in, ranges B8 to F20 and another set of cells in range B2 to F2
If a number in cell range B8 to F20 is same as one in range B2 to F2 I want to highlight the cell in range B8 to F20

Any help appreciated, I'm pulling my hair out :-)

Comment: Always a number in B1:F20 will be the same of a number of B2:F2 as the first includes the second if the are in the same sheet. Are they in different sheets?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.There will always be numbers in B8:F20 and some will be the same, numbers in cells B2:F2 will change frequently, they are in the same sheet - EDITED

Comment: Oops, original post should have said B8:F20 sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try custom formula:

Set custom formula in cell B2

```
=countif($B8:$F20,B2)
```

Apply to range B2:F2

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It didn't work though, it highlighted the cells in B2:F2 and I want cells B8:F20 highlighting, I did reverse it to =countif($B2:$F2,B8) but that didn't work either :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try selecting cells B8:F20 and click Format > Conditional formatting > Custom formula is:

`=arrayformula(sum(n(value(B8)=arrayformula(value({$B$2:$F$2})))))`

Comment: I made an example sheet - let me know if this is what you wanted: https://goo.gl/TbGyIX